# cast column to bytea type in postgresql for pgm_sym_decrypt in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**Please don't close this question. It's not a duplicate**

I'm very new to fastapi and python altogether.
I'm using `pgcrypto` module to encrypt the personal info of the customers.
My raw query is

```
select pgp_sym_decrypt(cast(email as bytea), 'secret_key') as email
from customers
```

and the query works fine.
How to produce something similar in `SqlAlchemy`? I've tried something like this

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func, cast, LargeBinary
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import BYTEA
```

```
customer = select(func.pgp_sym_decrypt(cast(Customer.c.email, 'bytea'), 'secret_key'))
```

Also tried

```
customer = select(func.pgp_sym_decrypt(cast(Customer.c.email, BYTEA), 'secret_key'))
```

Also tried

```
customer = select(func.pgp_sym_decrypt(cast(Customer.c.email, LargeBinary), 'secret_key'))
```

But no luck anywhere.
So, how to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pgp_sym_decypt` function takes a `BYTEA` as its argument, but `pgp_sym_encrypt` takes a `VARCHAR`, so casting is unnecessary.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test', echo=True, future=True)

tbl = sa.Table('t70770085', sa.MetaData(),
               sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
               sa.Column('name', sa.String))
tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
tbl.create(engine)

SECRET = 'secret_key'

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert().values(name=sa.func.pgp_sym_encrypt('Alice', SECRET)))

with engine.connect() as conn:
    query = sa.select(sa.func.pgp_sym_decrypt(sa.cast(tbl.c.name, sa.LargeBinary), SECRET))
    result = conn.execute(query)
    print(result.scalar_one())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me. I was clueless af